# Identification: short story about an astronaut who travels back in time to stop himself

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, short-stories

I read a story 2 years ago about an astronaut on Earth who was preparing for his flight that will occur in 2-3 months. He wakes up and sees a guy in full astronaut suit that tries to kill him. The guy is identical to him.

He survives and kills the guy, but half an hour later another astronaut appears trying to stop him. He avoids him and then another one appears.

At the end he is fleeing in his car and thousands of astronauts appear until they stop the car and kill him.

The astronauts were him trying to stop himself because, in the future, he hits a hole in time-continuum while traveling in space.

Does anyone know which short-story is this?

Comment: Funny.  By stopping himself, he probably *still created* the hole.  Can someone say "paradox"?

Comment: Sounds like the kind of time travel stories Larry Niven writes.

Comment: Sounds like Stoney Stevenson or Winston Niles Rumfoord having a bad dream... being described by Fredric Brown.

Comment: Not a Larry Niven story, although it shares some plot elements with his short story "Singularities Make Me Nervous".

Comment: This sounds a *lot* like The Explorer by James Smythe, except that novel takes place in space.

Comment: Reminds me a bit of "The Seventh Voyage" of "The Star Diaries" (Lem)

Comment: How is getting killed better than going thru the hole in time.

Comment: Similar to the short story "Singularities Make me Nervous" by Larry Niven but the ending is wrong and you state it is a book.

Comment: It is a short story. I have amended question to clarify. Sorry

Answer (score 6):

Could it be "The Seventh Voyage" by Stanislaw Lem?

> Space Traveler Ijon Tichy travels through a time vortex in an attempt to help himself fix a defect in his spaceship. This sets off a chain of time loops in which many versions of himself interact with each other (From The Star Diaries).

I'm not sure if it's the right story; the summary doesn't mention the versions trying to kill each other (but then I haven't read it), but I read the quote and thought of this question.

Comment: I don't think the description of the OP sounds like that story, no.

Answer (score 4):

It's sort of the emerging theme in the ["Dr McNinja"](http://drmcninja.com) web comic though it's hard to guess at which point in the series the writer developed the plan to tie everything together in this manner.